# How to restrict users with update permissions in Salesforce to be read-only in Workbench?

Tags: permissions, workbench, read-only

I would like to have some of our user community use Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php) to Salesforce, but I would like for them to have read-only access, not updates.  It seems to me that if a user is allowed to update objects with their account in the normal Salesforce UI, they inherit the same update permissions for Workbench.

Is there a way to allow users update capabilities in Salesforce UI, but restrict them to read-only in Workbench?  If updates can't be blocked, is there a way to prevent mass updates of multiple records?

I know you can restrict read-only to Workbench by making the user's permissions read-only.  However, I need the users to be read-only just in Workbench, but still allow them to update when logging in to Salesforce itself.

Thank you.

Comment: A user's permissions apply no matter how they login

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Workbench settings to do only queries](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285677/workbench-settings-to-do-only-queries)